# sudo ionic run android not working

Tags: android, environment-variables

I am trying to run a hybrid app on my android phone using ionic using the following command:

> sudo ionic run android

However I keep receiving this error :

> Error: Failed to find 'ANDROID_HOME' environment variable. Try setting
>   setting it manually. Failed to find 'android' command in your 'PATH'.
>   Try update your 'PATH' to include path to valid SDK directory.

I have already added platform tools & tools to PATH updated ANDROID_HOME to point to my sdk root.

The `ANDROID_HOME` environment variable shows up when I run `env` and the `PATH` has the tools and platform tools too. Additionally I can execute `android` too. It launches the SDK Manager as expected.

Please help! This is driving me up the wall!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`sudo` sanitizes the environment and by default only keeps certain environment variables available with modifying the values of some (e.g. `PATH`).

You can pass the variable `ANDROID_HOME` manually:

```
sudo ANDROID_HOME="/actual/path" ionic run android
```

Or preserve the current environment:

```
sudo -E ionic run android
```